# Post request dispatch/scala, getting http error 415

Tags: scala, http

I'm new to Scala and Dispatch and i'm trying to send a POST request, and since yesterday I cannot find out why this is not working.

First, I made a method for a GET request which is working well, here is the code:

```
def request(URL: String): String = {
   val service = url(URL).GET
   var ret = "{\"error\":0}"

   val result = Http(service).either.map {
     case Left(error) => {
      }
     case Right(response) => {
       if (response.getStatusCode == 200)
         ret = response.getResponseBody
       else
         ret = "{\"error\":" + response.getStatusCode + "}"
     }
   }
   Await.result(result, 10 seconds)
   ret
 }
```

Now i'm trying to do the same with POST request as follow:

```
def request(URL: String): String = {
   val service = url(URL).POST.setContentType("application/json", "UTF-8").addParameter("login", "root").addParameter("password", "root")
   var ret = "{\"error\":0}"

   val result = Http(service).either.map {
     case Left(error) => {
      }
     case Right(response) => {
       if (response.getStatusCode == 200)
         ret = response.getResponseBody
       else
         ret = "{\"error\":" + response.getStatusCode + "}"
     }
   }
   Await.result(result, 10 seconds)
   ret
 }
```

I tried differents syntaxes, with the "<<\?" etc... I find this one more readable.
Anyway, whatever the syntaxe i choose, the result is the same, here i get a 415 HTTP error. But when I send the exactly same request with postman, it is working, and I can't figure out why...

Any idea? Thanks

EDIT

I tried removing the setContentType and replace

```
val service = url(URL).POST.setContentType("application/json", "UTF-8").addParameter("login", "root").addParameter("password", "root")
```

by

```
val service = url(URL).POST.addParameter("login", "root").addParameter("password", "root")
```

but this is still not working.

EDIT 2

I needed to set Content-Type to multipart/form-data, I did something like:

```
val service = url(URL).POST.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8").addParameter("login", "root").addParameter("password", "root")
```

it is the consumed format, but now what i've got with this is a 400 HTTP error...

Comment: Are you trying to send those params in the query string or in the post body?  Also why set the content type to application/json when you are not sending json.

Comment: i'm trying to send them il the post body. I though it was necessary because i'm receiving json, but may be not.

Comment: Try it without setting the content type. That header tells the receiving server what kind of data is in the body. If it doesn't match what's actually in there then it could cause issues.

Comment: @Charrette Did you try it without content Type?

Comment: I edited my post, still not working with 415 http error again

Comment: Seems like setRequestHeader method does not exist, i tried with setHeader and it's still the same

Comment: Since the request works via postman but not dispatch you should try and use something to display each full request (like tcpmon or some other tunnel) so you can see what the differences between the two requests are. Figure out what's different and that will be a clue on how to fix this.

Comment: Okay i'll try and come back to you, thanks

Comment: Also if you are truly trying to send the data as form encoded params in the post body try setting the content type to: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code instead:

```
val client = new DefaultHttpClient()
URL.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
URL.setHeader("Accept", "application/json")
val obj = new JSONObject()
obj.put("login", "root")
obj.put("password", "root")
URL.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString, "UTF-8"))
val response = client.execute(URL)
```

Comment: I assume this is working but i'd like to do it in the dispatch's way, i have to use it